# In typescript how do you add generics to a function you expect to invoke with .call

Tags: typescript

```
interface Wrapped<T> {
  data: T;
}

interface BetterWrapper<T> {
  betterData: T;
}

function abc<T>(test: Wrapped<T>): BetterWrapper<T> {
  return {betterData: test.data}
}

const result = abc<string>.call({}, { data: 'hello' });
```

Given something like the above, I'm seeing an error that says cannot find name call.  I'm guessing that's because the return type is a string, if so what's the right now to represent this in typescript?

Comment: The generics are carried over to the type of the `call` method of every function. Do not pass explicit type argumentals! Write `abc.call` not `abc<string>.call` but if you want to be awkward, passing the type argument explicitly, it would be `abc.call<string>`

Comment: @AluanHaddad `abc.call<string>` doesn't work (`call` takes 3 type parameters: the `this` type, the argument types as a tuple type, and the return type).

Comment: Good point, I forgot about the extra parameters. Best to just use inference.

Comment: hey, thanks for the comments, I updated my question to better reflect what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm having trouble specifying the actual return value of the function and with the .call chaining

Comment: Inference often doesn't work, especially as the generic function gets more complex. But even something as simple as this doesn't work:

`function foo<T, This>(this: This, f: (x:T) => void) {}`

`foo.call(this, function(this: MyClass, x: number) {});`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution by declaring an interface where `call` has the required generic signature: you can use `abc.call<string>(...)` or just `abc.call(...)` and let the type parameter be inferred.

```
interface AbcInterface {
  <T>(test: Wrapped<T>): BetterWrapper<T>;
  call<T>(thisObj: object, arg: Wrapped<T>): BetterWrapper<T>;
}
const abc: AbcInterface = test => ({betterData: test.data});

// result: BetterWrapper<string>
const result = abc.call({}, { data: 'hello' });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgB0xAJgHgBUA+ZAbwChllc4w4AuZQgbgoF8KLRJZEUAQhDC90WHFCKlK1AEbDeAETqNmbTt3DR4SZAEFZCAJJa+umcikAKSAGcwTMdjxSAlEyEjoTiVLbUEOAAbIOswAAtgWwB5WQArJgB7eIgEMAAaZDgoAHNHDGcCEndkT1EC3xJ1CgREkHsswyYDY1MdFABeZDswZA7SKzJ5LyhleiYegDpaenZXNgoAekXkKAhbAFcgh1KFbwrofHsoUBziGrqGtc3tvsaEScCQwfZMshoVJgBycIgQxK+yDmbCAA)